MaterialUI Slider restrictions
I have 8 sliders with a range of 0-100 and 5 marks at 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100. I want the user to be able to distribute 350 points across the 8 sliders. Each step obviously consumes 25 points or returns them if you move back.
I tried to disable the sliders after 350 points have been spent, but then I can't slide them back (since they're disabled lol). Only resetting with an extra button works but that is a very not so elegant solution. Also just clicking on a mark can bypass the limit.

Solution 1
You can move the slider programmatically to its maximum value if it would exceed it - you can either use onChange or onChangeCommitted props to achieve that. It would probably look like this:
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  function handleChange(_, newValue) {
    const maxValue = getMaxValue();
    if (newValue > maxValue) {
      setValue(maxValue);
    } else {
      setValue(newValue);
    }
  }

//...
  return (
    <Slider
      value={value}
      onChange={handleChange}
      //other props...
    />
  )


In this solution, all you have to do is to figure out how to store the values of each slider, how to implement the getMaxValue function and how to inform the user they tried to move over the limit. Perhaps the slider (or its background) could blink in red color? Displaying the limit and updating it on every change would help too.
Solution 2
Check out Restricted values in the docs. You've got those marks at 0, 25, 50, 75 and 100 - remove the marks above the limit. At the same time keep the max={100} prop. max is responsible for the length of the slider, and marks determine what values can be set - and it turns out max doesn't have to be among them:
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";

const marks = [
  {
    value: 0,
    label: "0°C",
  },
  {
    value: 25,
    label: "25°C",
  },
  {
    value: 50,
    label: "50°C",
  },
  //no marks at 75 and 100
];

function valuetext(value) {
  return `${value}°C`;
}

export default function DiscreteSliderValues() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 300 }}>
      <Slider
        aria-label="Restricted values"
        defaultValue={20}
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        step={null}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        marks={marks}
        max={100}
      />
    </Box>
  );
}


(this is modified "Restricted values" code sample)
In this solution you also have to figure out  how to store the values of each slider, but in this case you'll have to filter marks array on top os using getMaxValue.

Thanks, that is an interesting idea! I have tempered with something similar but discarded it rather quickly. Is it possible to have the slider at its maximum value without showing it?
For example if there is only 50 points left over and I move a slider from 0-50. Then all points would be spent and the slider shouldnt move to the right any further.
At this point I would declare 50 as the max value of this slider, correct? However I want the slider to still appear as if the thumb was in the middle.

Yes, I've added another solution to my answer
